# How to ignore strings that are not valid

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime

random_list = ["lol", "2020-10-05", "2020-09-11"]
date_list = []

for item in random_list:
    try:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(item, "%Y-%m-%d")
        date_list.append(date)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid date foramt")


print(date_list)
```

In the above code, I am basically passing through some `random_list` and if i see a string that is of valid date format i want to add it another list called `date_list`.

I only want to add strings that are of valid date format meaning if i see a random string "foo" i want to ignore it and not append it to the `date_list`.

I guess what would be the best and most pythonic way to handle this?

Ideally if there were some boolean function that would tell me if the string i am looking at is a date then i would be able to just append strings to `date_list` when they return True upon validation.

I would love some thoughts on the correct way i can handle this.

Comment: This looks and sounds more like codereview than SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats a pretty good way to do it, you could implement it using a list comprehension or using the `filter` function

```
random_list = ["lol", "2020-10-05", "2020-09-11"]

def validate(date_text):
    try: datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d'); return True
    except ValueError: return False

random_list = list(filter(validate, random_list))

print(random_list)

#or 

[i for i in random_list if validate(i)]
```

both will give you:

```
["2020-10-05", "2020-09-11"]
```

if you want to convert its easiest to use the list comprehension *with* filter

```
[datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d') for i in list(filter(validate, random_list))]
```

```
[datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 11, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: the `== True` test is unnecessary

Comment: the list comprehension with filter might be cheaper expressed without the filter/list calls by doing inline if like this: `[datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d') for i in random_list if validate(i)]`

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you are using the specific format YYYY-MM-DD you can trivially do it via regular expressions.  Something like this:

```
import re
import datetime
rDate = re.compile(r'^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$')

isDate = lambda d: rDate.match(d)
toDate = lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")

random_list = ["lol", "2020-10-05", "2020-09-11"]
date_list = list(map(toDate, filter(isDate, random_list)))

print(date_list)
```

I get this result:

```
$ /bin/python ./dates.py
[datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 11, 0, 0)]
```